# Mess up SQL queries problem about count(*) and multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am a total beginner at studying databases. And I messed up my problem and have no idea how to solve this. Any advise is so appreciated,

Here are my two tables:

- employee: eid (string)
- info: eid (string), cid (string), qtr (quarter), year (integer)
- eid: employee id
- cid: course id (which employee take)
- qtr: quarter (spring, winter, summer)

`Info` is the table which has information about which courses were taken by each employee, given qtr and year. And course can only be taken once.

Employee can have gaps in enrollment (it is not necessary to take course every qtr)

I need to figure out:

List the number of courses for each quarter which at least one employee took it but fewer than employee took it (and I want to show qtr, year, count(*))

For example my output should look like below

```
qtr   year    num
-----------------
 W    2001     2
 W    2002     1
 F    2003     1
```

Here is my code

```
select 
    a.qtr, a.year, a.count(*) AS num
from 
    info a 
where 
    (select * 
     from info b 
     where a.cid = b.cid and a.qtr = b.qtr and a.year = b.year and a.eid < b.eid)
group by  
    a.qtr, a.year
having 
    num > 0 and num < 3;
```

Comment: You don't need another SELECT in the WHERE. Remove it starting with `(select` all the way to the end of that `where` and then remove the closing `)`. Take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with getting the counts for each course for each quarter:

```
select cid, qtr, count(*) as num_employees
from info i
group by cid, qtr;
```

Now, you want the ones with the count between certain values.  That is filtering after the `GROUP BY`, so you use a `HAVING` clause:

```
select cid, qtr, count(*) as num_employees
from info i
group by cid, qtr
having count(*) > 0 and  -- redundant because all courses have at least one student to be in the table
       count(*) < 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is what you can do, firstly you need to be able to select all the distinct quarters per their respective year and simply get a count. How this can be achieved is like so:

```
SELECT infor.qtr, infor.year , count(distinct(data_a.cid)) as Num
From infor
Inner Join
(SELECT distinct qtr, year, cid, count(eid) as EIDCount
    From infor
    Group by  qtr, year, cid
    having count(eid) >= 1 and count(eid) < 3) data_a
on infor.qtry = data_a.qtr and infor.year = data_a.year
group by infor.qtr, infor.year
```

Basically you need to first be able to get all courses that have at least an employee taking it, this is done in the inner select. Once that is obtained, you can simply query the output but his time by counting the distinct courses taken.

Cheers